# Is a fully polynomial-time approximation scheme a polynomial-time approximation scheme

Tags: algorithm, complexity-theory, computation-theory

I want to know if an approximation scheme which is a fully polynomial-time approximation scheme - is it also a polynomial-time approximation scheme?

For example, an approximation scheme that runs in O(n<sup>2</sup>(1/ε)<sup>3</sup>）- we know it's a fully polynomial-time approximation scheme.

Is it also a polynomial-time approximation scheme? Thanks!

Here are two relevant problems (True-or-False):

1. An approximation scheme that runs in O(n​2/ϵ) for any fixed ϵ>0 is a
   fully polynomial-time approximation scheme.
2. An approximation scheme that runs in O(n2(1/ε)3）for any fixed ϵ>0 is
   a polynomial-time approximation scheme.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thank you for the interesting question. I did a little research and came up with this [very nice academic lecture](http://www.win.tue.nl/~mdberg/Onderwijs/AdvAlg_Material/Course%20Notes/lecture7.pdf) on PTAS (polynomial-time approximation scheme) and fully PTAS.

As stated in the lecture:

> The running time of the algorithm should be polynomial in n; its
>   dependency on ε can be exponential however. So the running time can be
>   O((2 ^ (1/ε)) * n^2 ) for example, or O(n ^ (1/ε)), or O((n ^ 2)/ε), etc. If the
>   dependency on the parameter 1/ε is also polynomial then we speak of a
>   fully polynomial-time approximation scheme (FPTAS). In this lecture we
>   give an example of an FPTAS.

Since the demand from ε in PTAS is to be of an exponential dependency, then cleary FPTAS is a sub-case of PTAS, since the 1/ε is of a polynomial dependency ( O(FPTAS) < O(PTAS) )

Bottom line - FPTAS is PTAS.

Comment: Thanks for your help.